# Killing activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, kill

Here is the code for back button. I want to kill other activities by back button but its not working in one activity, but I have other activities and without one activity its working fine. Please help me out.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Can you define not working? what exactly you want to do? Kill all other activity in your app?

Comment: If you want to kill your running activity on back press so just call finish(); that's it

Comment: yes I want to kill all other activity in my app. MagicalPhoenix.

Comment: What's issue with using this code in a SPECIFIC activity if it works at all other places?

Comment: In your code where you handle back functionality just use finish(); it will kill/finish the previous running activity.before going further take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 2):

Might be this code will help you:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: MagicalPhoenix, What is activity here? as I am new in android. Can you please define?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Flags according to API level :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
{
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
}
else
{
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps ツ

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:noHistory="true"` in activities tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` which you don't want to save in stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define one local broadcast receiver on top most parent activity or base activity :

```
private final class KillReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    finish();
  }
}
```

Intialize and register broadcast receiver in onCreate() and unregister in onDestroy() on top most parent activity or base activity :

private KillReceiver clearActivityStack;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    clearActivityStack = new KillReceiver();
    registerReceiver(clearActivityStack, IntentFilter.create("clearStackActivity", "text/plain"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(clearActivityStack);
}
```

Now call broadcast receiver when wan to clear all previous activity :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent clearIntent = new Intent("clearStackActivity");
    clearIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendBroadcast(clearIntent);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```